# Python cannot find modules after upgrading from 2.6 to 2.7

Tags: python, module, version, importerror

Specifically, Python is unable to find SQL Alchemy.

Running easy_install does not help, as easy_install thinks SQL Alchemy is already installed and lists the path as

```
/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.7.3-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg
```

I tried (in a desperate attempt) to fix the problem by simply changing `python2.6` to `python2.7` in the path, but... obviously that didn't work.

Does anyone know what's going on and how to fix it?

**Edit**: Currently i'm using `sys.path.append()` to simply append the above path during the script's execution, which is working *okay*. I'm concerned that this is just a temporary solution to a much bigger problem, however.

Comment: We upgraded by downloading the tarball from python.org and installing it manually (./configure; make; make install) - we had to do it this way because our `yum` was acting funny.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either change the symbolic link between Python that reflects when you just type the Python command with `ln -s /path/to/target /path/to/shortcut` or explicitly call your Python 2.7 binary when installing packages like `/usr/lib/python2.7/python /path/to/application.py`

Comment: Basically we solved it by installing new libraries for 2.7. It was pretty much the best option since we needed both 2.6 and 2.7 on the system, but it was difficult since we had to do everything manually (and SQL Alchemy hasn't been our best friend in the past, ha).

Answer (score 2):

you've probably just installed python2.7 in addition to python2.6, so you now have two python versions on your system and `easy_install` still runs with 2.6.

check if there is a `easy_install-2.7` on your system, that should install the packages to the right directories.

Comment: No luck there, unfortunately. It makes sense that easy_install is still running with 2.6 - i'll see if i can update easy_install.

Answer (score 1):

Your Python 2.7 installation is not your system default python, so `easy_install` will run on Python 2.6 (or anything your `/usr/bin/python` points to), as the `easy_install` script uses `#!/usr/bin/python`.

As Christian suggested, you could change your `python` symlink so that it points to Python 2.7 and not 2.6. You could also use update-atlernatives to do so.